# How to set MaterialSwitch thumbTint programmatically

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I've implemented a function to change the themes in my app, before I had multiple themes I used a selector with different states for the MaterialSwitch like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/colorSwitch" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

This will be added to the switch in the layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <com.google.android.material.materialswitch.MaterialSwitch
       android:id="@+id/sw_update_list"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:thumbTint="@drawable/thumb_style"
       android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
       android:layout_centerInParent="true"
       android:checked="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How ca I do this programmatically?

Comment: You do not have the namespace app defined in the xml.

Comment: I've and it works, but I want to do this not with xml.

Comment: It is not a valid XML when all the namespaces are not defined.  Some libraries may ignore the error, but it is wrong.  I can easily do this with Powershell, but the namespace must be defined properly.

Comment: I added all namespaces, everything is working but I want to do it programmatically in my activity / fragment instead of the xml solution

Comment: Update posted XML so it contains the changes.

Comment: So I guess you don't understand what I want. It has nothing to do with xml layouts. I want to do it programmatically, the xml above is just the example how I add the selector file with the different states.

Comment: I understand perfectly.  You said you modified the xml to include the namespace.  I want to see the modified xml.

Comment: I edited it, but I still don't get why you want to see it.

Comment: You can create the XML either through the MaterialSwitch UI or from any XML library (like Power Shell).  I can do it in PS, but you probably want to do it similar to the following : https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/declaring-layout

Comment: You can check out the answer, I figured it out by myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooo, I figured it out by myself.

```
 val thumbTintSelector = ColorStateList(
            arrayOf(
                intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_checked),
                intArrayOf(-android.R.attr.state_checked)
            ),
            intArrayOf(
                // Color when the switch is checked
               Color.parseColor("#000000"),
                // Color when the switch is unchecked
                 Color.parseColor("#938F99")
            )
        )
        switchUpdatelist.thumbTintList = thumbTintSelector
```